# What is this "Thing" on my network?

Tags: ip-address

I was using AMD's magic packet utility to build a list of computers to do wake-on-lan and it found these entries:

```
224.0.0.22  igmp.mcast.net  01-00-5e-00-00-16
224.0.0.252 *NameNotFound*  01-00-5e-00-00-fc
239.255.255.250 *NameNotFound*  01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa
```

First of all, I'm not sure why it would find these. They're not in the subnet I provided.  I've never heard of them before; if they're reserved or not.

Feel free to offer a more descriptive title to this question and delete this comment.  I'm not sure how to describe what I'm seeing, google only makes fun of me when I ask it this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All perfectly normal to see in a modern network. They are all IPv4 multicast addresses. Here's a brief breakdown and you can read up in depth on your own:

224.0.0.22 - IGMP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/224.0.0.22

224.0.0.252 - LLMNR - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_Multicast_Name_Resolution

239.255.255.250 - SSDP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol

Answer (score 4):

Those are multicast addresses.  Multicast addresses are used when a single packet is intended to be sent to multiple recipients. Refer to http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/ for a list of service what each address typically corresponds to.

Answer (score 3):

all look like multicast packets to me;

- 224.0.0.22 - IGMP [ maybe you have some multicast-enabled media player
  ].
- 224.0.0.252  - [Link-local Multicast Name Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_Multicast_Name_Resolution)
- 239.255.255.250 - [upnp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPNP) - can be your router or client machine.

Answer (score -1):

I bet you have a Smart TV hooked to your internet? I do and I noticed that same thing and with in the description of the data transfer that showed on my network monitor program was the word Vizio, which is my TV. It might be your TV, the funny thing with this for me is I have that option with in the TV shut off so it doesn't share my viewing data but yet it is still sharing and transmitting data over my internet, kind of creepy I guess they just put the setting there to make you feel good but it actually doesn't do anything.